# JavaScript pushing to index 1 instead of 0

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a JavaScript variable, and I'm trying to initialize it in another function, with the following `for` loop:

```js
var test = {
    det: [{x: -1, y: -1}]
};

for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        test.det.push({x:10+i, y:10});
}

console.log(test.det);
```

For some reason, I still get `-1 & -1` as my values of `x & y`when I try to access `test.det[0]`. I only get the first values pushed when I access index 1. It seems like all my indices are shifted but I have no idea why that would be happening.

Comment: But `.push()` always adds to the end of the array, and your array starts off with one thing in it.

Comment: I see. I am not too familiar with javascript it appears the `det: [{x: -1, y: -1}]` line in my `test` is the first item in the array?

Comment: Right. If you want to start with an empty array just use `[]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Array#push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) will add another item after the current last item. To re initialize use assignment `=`:

```js
var test = {
  det: [{x: -1, y: -1}]
};

for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  test.det[i] =  ({x:10+i, y:10});
}

console.log(test);
```

Or just clear the array, and use `Array#push`:

```js
var test = {
  det: []
};

for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  test.det.push({x:10+i, y:10});
}

console.log(test);
```

Comment: Note that with this code there is no reason to declare the contents of `det`. Just use `var test = { det:[] }`

Comment: @Phrogz - I think that he tries to reinitialize an existing array. If not, he can start with `var test = { det:[] }` and use push.